# Converting to date5. format in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a column which has mixed values of month and date (its in character $5 format).
  `date
  7/23
  5/23
  23MAR
  7/19`

I want the data to come as uniform date5. format like this

`date
23MAR
23MAY
23MAR
19JUL.`

Here is the code that I'm using

```
data DAte_check4again;
 set Date_2test;
  format check_dt date5.;
  check_dt=datepart(date);
  run;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with macro code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS stores DATE, TIME and DATETIME values as numbers.  The DATEPART() function you are trying to use is for converting DATETIME values to DATE values.  But your source variable is character with a length of 5. (FORMATs are just instructions for how to display values).

So your first problem will be to convert the string into a DATE value.  You can then take the first 5 characters of the DATE. format and store that into either your original variable or some other variable. Assuming that the month/day values are for the current year and you only have those two styles of strings here is one method to generate a date and also the 5 character string.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  if index(date,'/') then date_ck = input(cats(date,'/',year(today())),mmmddyy10.);
  else date_ck = input(cats(date,year(today())),date9.);
  format date_ck date9.;
  new_date = substr(put(date_ck,date9.),1,5);
run;
```